What does 身を起こしている mean?

空はコンクリートフロアに両ひざと両手をついていた。倒れ込みはしなかったものの、強度の脱力感から身を起こしているのがやっとだ。

As far I know 身を起こしている means to wake up why is used to describe a character with hands and knees on the floor?

Do you know the literal meaning of the words 身 and 起こす?

This 起こす refers to the action of lifting the upper body of someone from a completely flat position. For example, helping a patient who is lying on their back in bed to sit up can be expressed as 体を起こす.
